# How to get the music files from the library

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i need to get the music files from the phone library.For that iam using the MPMediaPickerCOntroller.But it doesn't fire the didpickingitem delegate method.My code like below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
MPMediaPickerController *picker =[[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];
picker.delegate                     = self;
picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;
picker.prompt                       =@"Add songs to play";
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated: YES];
}

 - (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection 
   {
        NSLog(@"sdfadsf");
        NSLog(@"%@",mediaItemCollection);
        NSArray *slist=[mediaItemCollection copy];
         NSLog(@"%@",slist);

  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this in `viewDidUnload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you declare the MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate in your .h?

ex:

> @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

If you do not that would explain why the method isn't firing. Also, I do not believe it will work on the simulator; only on devices.

EDIT:

```
-(IBAction)presentLibrary:(id)sender
{
    //this is called from a button press, but you could do it in viewDidLoad
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
    picker.prompt  = NSLocalizedString (@"Select any song from the list", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");
    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];    
}

- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
     NSLog(@"didpick");
    if (mediaItemCollection) {
        [_mediaPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
        _mediaCollection = mediaItemCollection;
    }

    [mediaPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: S i declared that one.i tested on simulator.

Comment: @user1400581 Yeah the simulator does not have Music so you cannot test on it. I also edited my post to show you how I present the media picker. Note the didPick method only gets called when the media picker is up and the user selects a song.

Answer (score 0):

Read from here [The Music Player Framework in iPhone](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/)

Comment: Not it's for iPod Touch, iPhone and iPad. It is just called the iPod library.